# my project's routes return 404 when WebStorm 7.0.1 is open

Tags: node.js, webstorm

This is the situation:
WebStorm is open.

1. I run node app.js
2. I get : Server is listening on port 7777
3. I open chrome, and go to: localhost:7777.
4. I get: 404 Not Found WebStorm 7.0.1
5. when I close webstorm and do the same things everything works fine.

Anybody can help?

Thnx

Comment: What port is your app running at? You chose `7777` In your nodejs code? Does it work correctly when run from the command line? Are there any other errors in the console? I use Webstorm, and haven't ever seen this behavior, so it's likely something simple. Without more details added to your question, it's nearly impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: yes, it works correctly from the command line. There are no errors in the console. Thanx for trying anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,
The Webstorm Support helped me out...
My built-in server port was 7777. I changed this setting to another number and now everything works...

Answer (score 1):

You might have an instance of node already running: ps aux | grep node. If you do kill it and then use webstorm for running node.